# regex to print only matched string not the whole line using awk

Tags: awk

I'm trying to match only the ID "549d40r0-1e1b-01v8-0d72-0a8f2c680100" from the below data, I have the pattern match using the regex, however need to match only the ID not the whole line has the pattern match. Can you please help me using AWK.

Here is the regex: 
    ([a-z0-9]*-[a-z0-9]*-[a-z0-9]*-[a-z0-9]*-[a-z0-9]*):

```
[SyncThread:server:_88285] ERROR SyncThread.logDeliveryFailure(1535) - 
Delivery for server threw runtime exception. Failed to send data: 549d40r0-
1e1b-01v8-0d72-0a8f2c680100: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: 
connect -- Connection refused:
```

Thanks and regards,

Comment: does ID value occupy multiple lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Solution 1st:*** In case your id(string which you posted in your post) is on a single line and you want to look only for a specific string then following may help you on same.

```
awk -v var="549d40r0-1e1b-01v8-0d72-0a8f2c680100" '{if(match($0,var)){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENTH)}}'  Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk -v var="549d40r0-1e1b-01v8-0d72-0a8f2c680100" 'match($0,var){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENTH)}'   Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** In case your id(string which you posted in your post) is on a single line and you want to match it with a regex(as per only shown examples) then following may help you on same.

```
awk '{if(match($0,/[0-9a-z]+\-[0-9a-z]+\-[0-9a-z]+\-[0-9a-z]+\-[0-9a-z]+:/)){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENTH)}}'   Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk 'match($0,/[0-9a-z]+\-[0-9a-z]+\-[0-9a-z]+\-[0-9a-z]+\-[0-9a-z]+:/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'  Input_file
```

Comment: The second soln i have tried matches the whole line has the given ID. Th input file has many ID file like i mentioned should be matched.

Comment: @user3834663, if you want to print only matched ids then check my edited solutions and let me know how it goes then.